# How to build OpenSP for German messages?

Tags: perl, validation, sgml

I am trying to build OpenSP, setting the output message language as German.

I have set the LANG variable in sp-generate.mak file and executed the make file and after which i built OpenSP. The problem is that the messages are still in English. How can I change the language to German?

This is the official build instruction: http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/build.htm

Unfortunately it is not helpful. Has anyone got an idea how to build this in Windows and Linux? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Has this something to do with [tag:w3c-validation]?

Comment: So are you having this problem on Windows only?  The instructions for Linux on the site are different anyway.

Comment: I am having issues in windows right now also I haven't figured out how to do in Linux yet. http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/autoconf.htm
I am not sure how to specify the language in linux.